# how to get the total row count with mysqli

Tags: mysql, count, row

i am trying to understand mysqli extension and did google but got very few info on this except php.net which was helpful.

now after all this i am trying to achieve what i could with mysql extension which is as follows:

```
// MYSQL STYLE OF fetching array, query limit and perform total row count all at once

$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, post.id as pid, bla bla FROM account ORDER BY pid ASC". $eb["array"]['querylimit'];

$result = mysql_query($sql, $eb["con"]);
$TotalRcount = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query("SELECT FOUND_ROWS()"));

// Performing record count [current]
// $RecordCount = mysql_num_rows($result);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    // read columns
}
```

with mysqli how can i achieve this? am sure i am missing many things. please help me with example on how to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using mysqli you do it the following way (assuming the mysqli object is already created -- you can also use the [procedure methods,](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php) just slightly different):

```
$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, post.id as pid, bla bla 
        FROM account ORDER BY pid ASC". $eb["array"]['querylimit'];
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
$TotalRcount = $result->num_rows;
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc()){
    $col1 = $row['col1'];  // col1 is a placeholder for whatever column you are reading
    //read columns
}
```

Comment: Thanks ajon, its working fine. i can get the columns values. but using num_rows gives the current number of rows which is not what i intend to achieve. i was trying to count the total number of rows. e.g. i have 35 rows and choose to view 10 queries per requests. like: showing 10 of 35 something like that.

Answer (score 5):

You may try this:

```
//Establish connection using mysqli api
$conn = mysqli_connect('hostname', 'username', 'password', 'database_name');

$sql = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS *, post.id as pid, bla bla FROM account ORDER BY pid ASC". $eb["array"]['querylimit'];

$sql2 = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";

$result1 = $conn->query($sql);
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
$TotalRcount = $result2->fetch_row();

// Performing record count [current]
// $RecordCount = $result->num_rows();

while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH)){
    // read columns
}
```

In a while loop i have used MYSQLI_BOTH constant but you may change it to MYSQLI_NUM or MYSQLI_ASSOC whichever you need.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I tried this and $TotalRcount = $result2->fetch_row(); returns an array with the actual total number of rows in index 0

Answer (score 1):

SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is generally used in SELECT statements with a LIMIT clause.

From the MySQL manual (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows):

> A SELECT statement may include a LIMIT clause to restrict the
>   number of rows the server returns to the client. In some
>   cases, it is desirable to know how many rows the statement
>   would have returned without the LIMIT, but without running
>   the statement again. To obtain this row count, include a
>   SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS option in the SELECT statement, and then
>   invoke FOUND_ROWS() afterward

In your example above, you don't use LIMIT to keep the number of results down so using FOUND_ROWS() will only mean an extra call back to the database. Please check out the other answers here for information on how to get the number of rows returned. Good luck.