# Single mysqli query statement to get total number of rows and limit also

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I want to fetch the total count of records in MySQL db table and also use the limit with this. For example, there are 100 rows and the limit I want to use let suppose is 10. I know how to do this using two queries but I want to do this in one go.

```
SELECT count(*) as total_rows FROM mytable; // gets the total count of rows

SELECT col1,col2 FROM mytable LIMIT 0, 10; // gets the 10 rows of col1,col2
```

I want to do this in one go. Any idea. 
Thanks.

Comment: you can't make it it one "go"

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20a6d7/1/0) that demonstrates how the below works:

```
SELECT m.*, 
(
  SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM mytable AS sm
) AS TotalCount
FROM (
  SELECT mt.col1, mt.col2
  FROM mytable AS mt 
  LIMIT 0, 10
) AS m
```

Comment: Just because you can doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Shayan Husaini's answer on [How to get the total row count with MySQLi](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682448/how-to-get-the-total-row-count-with-mysqli)

I have updated his original answer after trying it out myself. You have to add "SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS" after SELECT in your query and add a second query as shown in the code snippet below.

```
$sql1 = "SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS col1,col2 FROM mytable LIMIT 0, 10";
$sql2 = "SELECT FOUND_ROWS()";

$result1 = $conn->query($sql1);
$result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
$TotalRcount = $result2->fetch_row();

// I have added this next line to correct the answer
$TotalNumRows = $TotalRcount[0];
```

You can use $result1 to access your results as you normally would.